# Openlayers Css problem?

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

I have succeeded to show `Openlayers` map in my application, when i show css popup(not Openlayers Popup) map has to blank as the rest of the application. But `Openlayers` map is not getting blank.

What could be the problem?

Instead of `Openlayers` if i use `Google Maps` its getting blank when i show popup.

I am not using any css related to `Openlayers`, just i included this http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, if i understand your question correctly, the z-index of the "background" of your popup compared to OpenLayers.

When you include the OpenLayers.js file it loads it's own CSS, and somewhere in there it sets the z-index of the map div to about 1000 (i think).

Try to open Firebug and find the "gray overlay" that your popup places over the page, and ramp up it's z-index.